# jQuery drop down menu in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am looking for some help to change my jquery navigation menu into plain javascript. I have read lots of questions on converting jquery to javascript but I can't get my head around the changes.

Basically the jquery toggles the classes so the drop down menu shows and hides,

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.three-lines-menu').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $('.js-menu').toggleClass('js-menu-responsive');

    });
});
```

Here is where I am at with my plain javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

  var menu = document.getElementByClassName('js-menu'),

    toggleClass = function (el, cl) {
    hasClass(el, cl) ? removeClass(el, cl) : addClass(el, cl);

    toggleClass(menu, 'js-menu-responsive');

  };   
};
```

This is just my attempt from reading articles but I can't get it to work, any advice or a push in the right direction would be great.

*Note - I don't need support for ie 6,7,8

Here is my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zck98b42/)

Comment: May I ask why you'd want to translate your JQuery in the first place?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your fiddle: missing ')' update: http://jsfiddle.net/zck98b42/1/ additionaly, DOMContentLoaded doesn't execute anything in my chrome

Comment: It's just an experiment, I wanted to see if I could do it without jquery because its such a small amount of code and I didn't think it would be worth loading all of jquery for this one bit of functionality

Comment: even the min-version is too big? (95KB)

Comment: It's not a case of it being to big, is it not just excessive to load the entire library when you could just use plain javascript? I don't know . Maybe I should just use jquery, what do you think ?

Comment: Just in case you where interested, I got it working in plain javascript in my browser - See: jsfiddle.net/zck98b42/ heres the code. It doesn't work in the js fiddle for some reason but there is the code I used, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with what exactly you want, but if you are looking for dropdown using plain javascript try this link:
[jsfiddle/javascript-dropdown](https://jsfiddle.net/samps01/hd4rjtuk/)

```
    var clk = document.getElementById("clk");
clk.onclick = function() {
  var hid = document.getElementById("hidden");
  if (hid.classList.contains("hide")) {
    hid.classList.remove("hide");
    hid.classList.add("show");
  } else {
    hid.classList.add("hide");
    hid.classList.remove("show");
  }
}

document.getElementById("under").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML = "Undergraduate";
  if (document.getElementById("hidden").classList.contains("hide")) {
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.remove("hide");
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.add("show");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.remove("show");
  }
}
document.getElementById("grad").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML = "Graduate";
  if (document.getElementById("hidden").classList.contains("hide")) {
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.remove("hide");
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.add("show");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.remove("show");
  }
}
```